# Sending multiple unique emails at once in laravel (mailtrap.io)

Tags: php, laravel

I have an email array with the variables `email` and `signup_token`. I want to send the `signup_token` to the corresponding email in that array. How can I send multiple emails at once with unique content from an array in Laravel. I am using mailtrap. The array will be big, maybe up to 20-25 arrays in it (with emails and unique signup tokens). As I do it with foreach it goes really slow.

```
foreach(request('email_list') as $email) {
    array_push($emailList, [
        'email' => $email,
        'signup_token' => md5($email)
    ]);
    Mail::to($email)->send(new RegisterStudent(md5($email)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If foreach is slow for you, you can insert them into a database queue, and then you setup a worker that reads from that queue and sends them sequentially in the background.

This way you can scale your application's functionality from the beginning